# Kriging with gstat: including a random effect

Tags: r, geospatial, kriging, gstat

I am getting acquainted with `gstat` and kriging more generally in R. The end goal is to interpolate temperature across my spatial grid, and I want to be able to do so for different time points (average daily temperature over several years). So, I've been imagining an interpolation that estimates temperature and considers something like the season or year as a random effect. I've been exploring universal kriging, but I'm struggling to understand the formula set up.

I've included some example code using the `meuse` data (from `sp`). When I assign a variogram, I can state that my dependent variable is predicted by other variables and include random effects (rather than using something like `zinc~1`).

However, when I do this with `krige()`, the only alternative formula to `zinc~1` seems to be `zinc~x+y`. I believe the formula `zinc~x+y` is what allows anisotropy and avoids the stationarity assumption, but why can't I include other data here like I can with the variogram? Is it because it is already accounted for in the variogram, or am I not understanding something about kriging more generally?

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~ x+y
data(meuse.grid)
coordinates(meuse.grid) <- ~ x+y

# assigning and fitting the variogram
sample.vgm <- variogram(zinc~copper+(1|dist.m), # the formula - copper is a fixed effect, dist.m is a random effect 
                     meuse) # SPDF dataset

vgm.fit <- fit.variogram(sample.vgm, # the sample variogram 
                         model=vgm(model="Sph")) # assigning a model type

# kriging
z.krige <- krige(zinc~x+y, # the  formula
                 meuse, # the SPDF that has data
                 meuse.grid, # the SPDF to krige over
                 model=vgm.fit) 

# this doesn't work if the formula is anything besides ~1 or ~x+y
z.krige2 <- krige(zinc~copper+(1|dist.m),
                 meuse, 
                 meuse.grid, 
                 model=vgm.fit)
```

I am using R version 4.1.3 on Windows 10 (x64).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/239301/kriging-using-multiple-spatial-input-variables-and-one-spatial-output-response/239534#239534), the explanatory variables apparently need to be loaded into the grid for Kriging to find them.

`dist` should work since it is already in the `meuse` grid:

```
# dist is in the grid
z.krige2 <- krige(zinc~dist,
  meuse, 
  meuse.grid, 
  model=vgm.fit)
```

For `copper` and `dist.m`, I've just added random values here:

```
# add random values for copper and dist.m into the grid
meuse.grid$copper <- runif(nrow(meuse.grid))
meuse.grid$dist.m <- runif(nrow(meuse.grid))

# now copper and dist.m variables are available
z.krige2 <- krige(zinc~copper+(1|dist.m),
  meuse, 
  meuse.grid, 
  model=vgm.fit)
```